# How to write a Specification Joining Two Tables with where attributes in different classes

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria

Boot Application and need a query with dynamic where field. Googling about it I've found Specifications could be an answer but how a make the where clause searching in attributes in different classes?

Here's my model

Brand Class

```
@Entity
public class Brand {

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="brand",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Cars> cars;
//Getter's and Setters
}
```

Car Class

```
@Entity
public class Car {

@Id
private Long id;
private String name;
private String carType;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private brand brand;
//Getter's and Setters
}
```

The repository is the strait one:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Car> {    
}
```

If the user enters the car's name and the brand i need something like the following jpql

```
 select c from car c join c.brand br where br.name = :brandName and c.name = :carName
```

Also the user can enter only with the type of the car, so the jpql will be:

```
select c from car c join c.brand br where br.name = :brandName and c.carType = :carType
```

Comment: If it's really going to be this without any other complex features it would cost a lot less time to just write those two queries and have an if/else to determine whether or not the name or the type was entered.

Answer (score 1):

Specifications are commonly used when you need to build dynamic queries. If your use case is limited to those two queries, I would rather write those as static queries and have a simple if/else to check if the name or type was provided.

When you use specifications and you follow the Spring guides, you should write an additional class that has your various specifications, for example:

```
public class CarSpecifications {
    public static Specification<Car> withBrandName(final String name) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            final Path<Brand> brandPath = root.get("brand");
            return cb.equal(brandPath.<String>get("name"), name);
        };
    }

    // TODO: withName, withType
}
```

You'll have to add multiple methods here, the method above is only for your `br.name = :brandName` clause.

Now, to use this class you have to write something like:

```
public List<Car> findCars(String brandName, String name, String type) {
    Specifications<Car> spec = Specifications
        .<>where(CarSpecifications.withBrandName(brandName));
    if (name != null) {
        spec.and(CarSpecifications.withName(name);
    }
    // TODO: if (type != null) ...

    return repository.findAll(spec);
}
```